# React event handler is not working at all

Tags: reactjs, eventhandler

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import iconsdown from  './iconsdown.png' ;
import iconsnext from  './iconsnext.png';


function Button() {
  const handleEvent=(e) =>{
      console.log(e.target);
      document.write(42);
      const list = e.target.parentElement;
      const icon_down = e.target;

    }
  return (
    <div className='ul'>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>View</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Extra</li>
        <li className="down" onClick={() =>handleEvent}><img alt={'THIS IS AN IM'} width={30} height={30} src={iconsdown} /></li>
        <li className="next"><img alt={'THIS IS AN IM'}width={50} height={50} src={iconsnext} /></li>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Button
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap :15px;
    right: 2em;
    top:2em
}

.ul_click{
    top : 9px
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:1.3em;
    gap:5px;
    height:2em
}

.next{
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
    left: 12em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.next_click{
    opacity: 1;
    animation: next 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes next {
    from{opacity:0 ;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}


.down{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.down_click{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity : 1;
    animation: clicking 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes clicking {
    from {opacity: 1}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'BeautifulPeoplePersonalUse';
    src: url(/BeautifulPeoplePersonalUse-dE0g.ttf) format('ttf');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is fairly simple demo. For some reason **onClick** event not working in Button app. I've tried on Chrome and Firefox. Used create-react-app and Vite . And the funny thing is it worked before but after some time event handler is not seems to responding .

i removed the screenshots and add code block .

Comment: It looks like it should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: Actually nothing . I've inserted firefox console screenshot

Comment: Try it without event.preventDefault()

Comment: Your JS code is correct. The best I can of is your arrows element is somehow overlapping with another element and thus your click event does not reach the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<li onClick={() => handleEvent()}></li>
```

I can't say why but this fixed a similar problem for me in a recent project.

Comment: don't seems to working

Answer (score 0):

If the function you pass to an event handler only needs the event as an argument, you don't need to call it using an anonymous function, it will be passed to your function implicitly. just do

```
onClick={handleEvent}
```

If you do want to pass it with an anonymous function because you prefer the syntax or have multiple arguments you need to pass to it then you need to pass it to your function in the event handler explicitly

```
onClick={(e) => handleEvent(e)}
```